# Is there any way to make multiple graphs in Javascript and show them as stacked cards?

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, canvasjs

I'm hoping to make an application which shows multiple graphs but show them as stacked cards. There can be a button nearby to cycle through the cards, or the user can hover on one of the graph-cards to highlight it. I've used CanvasJS before and while it has stacked graphs, it doesn't have anything for stacked cards. I've searched quite a bit but all I've found are ways to make stacked graphs, but sort of like what CanvasJS already has. I found [this code](https://github.com/geersch/stacker) to make some stacked cards, but I couldn't integrate CanvasJS graphs into it.

Does anyone know any way by which I can have graphs stacked on top of one another?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like it was more of an implementation issue, rather than framework. I found [this code](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/Stacked-Card-Style-Navigation-Menu-with-jQuery-CSS3.html) which works perfectly with my requirements.